# Jquery UI - Selectable - how to select continous line of table cells?

Tags: jquery-ui-selectable

I got Selectable working as far as filtering out the table cells I do not want to select:

http://jsfiddle.net/2F55j/5/

```
 $(function() {
   $( "table tr" ).selectable(
     {filter: ":not(.belegt)"}
   );
});
```

Now I would like to only select cells next to each other, that form a continous line. So when there is a filtered out cell in between, the one after it cannot be selected.

On a sidenote:  when I select cells in row 1, then select some in row 2, the selected ones in row 1 do not get removed..How to get this to work?

Could you help me please?
I have been on this now for hours and it just won't work.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $( "table tr" ).selectable({
        filter: "td",
        start: function(event, ui){
            $("td.ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");    
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            var selected = $("td.ui-selected");
            if(selected.hasClass("belegt"))
                selected.removeClass("ui-selected");   
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: This code may help but it would be much more useful if there was also an explanation of how this code answers the users question.